# Automatic transfer data from the sql to R

Tags: r, dataframe, rodbc, sqldf

I get the data from the sql server to perform regression analysis, and then  the regression results i return back to another sql table.

```
library("RODBC")
library(sqldf)

dbHandle <- odbcDriverConnect("driver={SQL Server};server=MYSERVER;database=MYBASE;trusted_connection=true")

sql <- 
  "select
Dt
,CustomerName
,ItemRelation
,SaleCount
,DocumentNum
,DocumentYear
,IsPromo

from dbo.mytable"

df <- sqlQuery(dbHandle, sql)

reg=lm(SaleCount~IsPromo,data=df)

#save to sql table
sqlSave(dbHandle, as.data.frame(reg), "dbo.mytableforecast", verbose = TRUE)  # use "append = TRUE" to add rows to an existing table

odbcClose(dbHandle)
```

The question:

The script works automatically, i.e. in the scheduler there is task that script in certain time was launched.
How to do that in the next time, when the script runs, it must work not with all table,  but only the data that was loaded in sql?

For example,  today was loaded 100 observations.
From 01.01.2017-10.04.2017
Script performed regression and returned data to sql table.
Tomorrow will loaded new 100 observations.
11.04.2017-20.07.2017
I.E. when tomorrow the data will loaded and the script will start at 10 pm, it must work only with data from 11.04.2017-20.07.2017, and not from 01.01.2017-20.07.2017

How can I do this?

data example from sql

```
df=structure(list(Dt = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 
15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 19L), .Label = c("2017-10-12 00:00:00.000", "2017-10-13 00:00:00.000", 
"2017-10-14 00:00:00.000", "2017-10-15 00:00:00.000", "2017-10-16 00:00:00.000", 
"2017-10-17 00:00:00.000", "2017-10-18 00:00:00.000", "2017-10-19 00:00:00.000", 
"2017-10-20 00:00:00.000", "2017-10-21 00:00:00.000", "2017-10-22 00:00:00.000", 
"2017-10-23 00:00:00.000", "2017-10-24 00:00:00.000", "2017-10-25 00:00:00.000", 
"2017-10-26 00:00:00.000", "2017-10-27 00:00:00.000", "2017-10-28 00:00:00.000", 
"2017-10-29 00:00:00.000", "2017-10-30 00:00:00.000"), class = "factor"), 
    CustomerName = structure(c(1L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
    17L, 18L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 11L, 12L, 
    13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
    9L, 10L), .Label = c("x1", "x10", "x11", "x12", "x13", "x14", 
    "x15", "x16", "x17", "x18", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5", "x6", 
    "x7", "x8", "x9"), class = "factor"), ItemRelation = c(13322L, 
    13322L, 13322L, 13322L, 13322L, 13322L, 13322L, 11706L, 13322L, 
    11706L, 13322L, 11706L, 13322L, 11706L, 13322L, 11706L, 13322L, 
    11706L, 13322L, 11706L, 13322L, 11706L, 13322L, 11706L, 13163L, 
    13322L, 158010L, 11706L, 13163L, 13322L, 158010L, 11706L, 
    13163L, 13322L, 158010L, 11706L), SaleCount = c(10L, 3L, 
    1L, 0L, 9L, 5L, 5L, 11L, 7L, 0L, 5L, 11L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 19L, 
    10L, 0L, 1L, 12L, 1L, 11L, 6L, 0L, 167L, 7L, 0L, 16L, 165L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 29L, 0L, 0L, 11L), DocumentNum = c(36L, 36L, 
    36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 51L, 36L, 51L, 36L, 51L, 36L, 51L, 
    36L, 51L, 36L, 51L, 36L, 51L, 36L, 51L, 36L, 51L, 131L, 36L, 
    89L, 51L, 131L, 36L, 89L, 51L, 131L, 36L, 89L, 51L), DocumentYear = c(2017L, 
    2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
    2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
    2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
    2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L), 
    IsPromo = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("Dt", "CustomerName", 
"ItemRelation", "SaleCount", "DocumentNum", "DocumentYear", "IsPromo"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -36L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a date to your result sql table `dbo.mytableforecast`

Change the select SQL statement such that it only selects data after

```
select
Dt
,CustomerName
,ItemRelation
,SaleCount
,DocumentNum
,DocumentYear
,IsPromo

from dbo.mytable

where Dt > (select max(Dt) from dbo.mytableforecast)
```

Comment: Thank you. One question. My Sheduler  runs 1 time per day, but it happens that the data in the database does not load every day, it can loaded   for example  1 time of 3 days and so on.
how in this case will  R script work?   will it stop working until new data be  received ? or it will the error.

Comment: I guess if you want to make sure that your script uses all the data that was not used before, you should extract the `max(Dt)` of the current set and store this in the database.

Comment: Wietze, one more question, Dt column is absent in dbo.mytableforecast, how can i set the condition

select
Dt
,CustomerName
,ItemRelation
,SaleCount
,DocumentNum
,DocumentYear
,IsPromo

from dbo.mytable "where Dt>the last date when the script worked"

Comment: You have to alter that table in SQL to incorporate the Dt column. I figured you manage these tables yourself.